# Reconstitution from reduction and tropicalization for $p$-adic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

For a variety $X$ over a $p$-adic field $k$, its reduction to a variety $X_p$ over residue field $k_p$ of $k$ and its tropicalization to $X_{tr}$ seem to me to be somewhat orthogonal processes.

Taken individually neither $X_p$ nor $X_{tr}$ suffices to reconstruct $X$ in general. The question is: how far can they go towards reconstruction when taken together?